# QGIS 3.16.11- Unable to calculate. Metadata error

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2

I have trouble with preprocessing Sentinel 2 images in QGIS 3.16.11.
I uploaded both the file which has Sentinel 2 bands B01~B12 and the file which has metadata, but it shows nothing.
Also, when I click the 'Run' button, it says "Error 37. unable to calculate: metadata error".
I don't know why it happens and how to solve it.

[image]